# Direct2D: Convert ID2D1Image to ID2D1Bitmap

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, direct2d

I'm working on a programm that needs to modify what is already on the screen.
So I only have a `ID2D1Bitmap` that i created using `pRenderTarget->CopyFromRenderTarget`.

What I'm trying to do is, applying effects to that Bitmap. The effect only returns `ID2D1Image`, but i need to have a `ID2D1Bitmap`.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit1:**

```
ID2D1Bitmap* myBitmap //the bitmap I want to apply the effect to
ID2D1Effect* effect = NULL;
pDeviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Saturation, &effect);
effect->SetValue(D2D1_SATURATION_PROP_SATURATION, 0.0f);
effect->SetInput(0, myBitmap);

ID2D1Image* pImg = NULL;
effect->GetOutput(&pImg);
```

If I cast this Image, getPixelSize() raises an access violation.

Comment: just cast the ID2D1Image as an ID2D1Bitmap

Comment: No this throws an access violation. It is possible to cast from ID2D1Bitmap to ID2D1Image since the ID2D1Bitmap interface inherits from ID2D1Image. But not the other way round.

Comment: Please, share a code snippet how you are creating and applying the effect(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it. It's dirty, but it works.

```
ID2D1Bitmap* convertImageToBitmap(ID2D1Image* pImg, D2D1_SIZE_U size)
{
    ID2D1Image* oldTarget = NULL;
    ID2D1Bitmap1* targetBitmap = NULL;

    //Create a Bitmap with "D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET"
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties =
        D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
        D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
    );
    pDeviceContext->CreateBitmap(size, 0, 0, bitmapProperties, &targetBitmap);

    //Save current Target, replace by ID2D1Bitmap
    pDeviceContext->GetTarget(&oldTarget);
    pDeviceContext->SetTarget(targetBitmap);
    //Draw Image on Target (if currently not drawing also call Begin/EndDraw)
    pDeviceContext->DrawImage(pImg);

    //Set previous Target
    pDeviceContext->SetTarget(oldTarget);

    oldTarget->Release();

    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct way to do it (although with error handling :)