# Direct2D tile limitation?

Tags: winapi, direct3d, direct2d

Is there a limitation on how much Direct2D tile size can grow?

In [D2D1_RENDERING_CONTROLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/ns-d2d1_1-d2d1_rendering_controls) I can set the tiling of the Direct2D buffering.

```
            D2D1_RENDERING_CONTROLS r4c = {};
            m_d2dContext->GetRenderingControls(&r4c);
            if (r4c.tileSize.width < (UINT32)wi || r4c.tileSize.height < (UINT32)he)
            {
                r4c.tileSize.width = wi;
                r4c.tileSize.height = he;
                m_d2dContext->SetRenderingControls(r4c);
                m_d2dContext->GetRenderingControls(&r4c);
                nop();
            }
```

When it's up to 4K resolution, the rendering of an effect gets the whole texture at one pass:

[image]

When I go up to 8K, then there's tiling, indicating that Direct2D passes the texture in more than one pass:

[image]

This is a killing for my [custom HLSL effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects) that require the whole texture to operate, like this special lighting effect.

Is this an intended feature? A bug? An undetected issue? Would I be forced to go to OpenGL rendering eventually?

This is not related to my GF card - I tested with an RTX 2070, the same error occurs.

Edit: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBFPPuRmNteR-k46LUCTmJNw3VPslrSq/view?usp=sharing) is a full VS 2019 solution with a simple swirl effect.

```
// When you try plain 1920x1080 or 3840x2160, ok
int wi = 7680;
int he = 4320;
// With the above, the swirling is tiled x4.
```

Edit: On EndDraw(), I have this in debug output:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBE6324B89 in d2dbug.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x000000EBC4D5CE58.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBE6324B89 in d2dbug.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x000000EBC4D5CE58.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBE6324B89 in d2dbug.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x000000EBC4D5CE58.
```

Comment: What happens if you don't call SetRenderingControls at all?

Comment: @SimonMourier the default tiling is 1024x1024, so the effect rendering fails at 1920x1080 as well.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more or provide some reproducing code? Built-in Direct2D effects don't "fail" at 1024/1080/etc afaik.

Comment: Failiing means that it doesn't render the texture at one pass. Which means that for shaders that require the whole texture to calculate, it wouldn't work (like the above lighting). For shaders that do not depend on the entire texture (like a blur or a hue rotation) there is no problem.

Comment: Btw the build-in displacement effect (erode or dilate) fails at high resolutions, it apparently requires the entire texture.

Comment: If by erode or dilate you mean morphology, I don't see any issue with it? I'm using the D2DPhotoAdjustment sample (replaced for example m_contrast by an m_morphology and use a 2000x1700 image)

Comment: It works up to 4K. 3840 x 2160. Try using a bigger image. BTW even with a larger image, the sample might be using the preview resolution, not the full image dimensions. In my application, when I'm displaying preview to the user, I'm scaling everything to the preview, so the preview works. It's the 8K rendering I have the problem.

Comment: According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/ns-d2d1_1-d2d1_rendering_controls#remarks): The renderer can allocate tiles larger than the minimum tile allocation. The allocated tiles will be powers of two of the minimum size on each axis, except that the size on each axis will not exceed the guaranteed maximum texture size for the device feature level.

Comment: But the limit of the time is 16384 pixels at feature level 11.

Comment: @SimonMourier I added a VS 2019 solution.

Comment: Yes, I have tried other ways and I do have a 4096x4096 max for rendering controls too, so any effect on image bigger than that will have issue if the effect needs another tile. Under that, everything works fine (if rc are changed to 4096). I don't see where that's coming from (I see the same limit with DirectX12), "maximum texture size" should be 16384 but maybe this is the result of some internal computation... you should ask Microsoft.

Comment: @SimonMourier I did, they asked me to provide this VS solution and (hopefully) they are investigating it. It also throws com exceptions in `EndDraw()` when the tile is big, hopefully they can find it based on that.

Comment: do you have a link to what you posted? I'm interested too :-)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/427400/direct2d-tile-bug-when-size-is-over-4k.html#comment-429618

They asked me in a private message to provide source code and I gave them the [VS project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBFPPuRmNteR-k46LUCTmJNw3VPslrSq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SimonMourier ++

Comment: @SimonMourier  check answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer from Microsoft.

> I would recommend using a bitmap as the input to the effect rather
> than the image source. Simply drawing the image source into that
> bitmap should work. They could also create the bitmap from a WIC
> bitmap source using the D2D API CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap.

This works, although the output of an effect returns a ID2D1Image which then has to be converted to a ID2D1Bitmap by the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118397/direct2d-convert-id2d1image-to-id2d1bitmap).

I'm still discussing with them the performance issues that might occur when there are too many effects in the chain and each of them has to convert manually to an ID2D1Bitmap.